# c# generics covariance and contravariance conflict

Tags: c#, generics, covariance, contravariance

I have the following code written in c# using interfaces, inheritance and generics:

```
public interface IBasic
{

}

public class Basic : IBasic
{

}

public class AnotherBasic : Basic
{

}

public interface IWorker<in TBasic>
{
    void Run(TBasic basic);
}

public class Worker : IWorker<Basic>
{
    public void Run(Basic basic)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class AnotherWorker : IWorker<AnotherBasic>
{
    public void Run(AnotherBasic basic)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public void Test()
{
    List<IWorker<IBasic>> workers = new List<IWorker<IBasic>>
    {
        new Worker(),
        new AnotherWorker()
    };
}
```

The problem of this code is that the worker and anotherworker classes do not fit in to the generics list of `IWorker<IBasic>` who are the parents of workers for both the worker and the basic class. The thing is that `IWorker<in TBasic>` is contravariant because of run method signature, however I need it covariant, in order to fill in the `List<IWorker<IBasic>>`. The run method has to have the TBasic parameter, and I need this list of workers on purpose of chain of responsibility design pattern. Do I miss something or did I find a reason to make covariance and contravariance not mutually exclusive ?

Comment: You can't do it because it would not be safe e.g. `new List<IWorker<IBasic>>{new AnotherWorker()}[0].Run(new Basic())` would compile but fail at runtime.

Comment: This looks like a [XYProblem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Whatever problem you are trying to solve with this design can likely be solved with a different design if you describe the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I obviously can solve this with number of approaches, but I want this to work the way I show it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after 2 days of learning and investigation I answered my own question. Here is the code:

public interface IBasic
    {

```
}

public class Basic : IBasic
{

}

public class AnotherBasic : Basic
{

}

public interface IWorker<in TBasic>
{
    void Run(TBasic basic);
}

public class SimpleWorker : IWorker<IBasic>
{
    public void Run(IBasic basic)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Worker : IWorker<Basic>
{
    public void Run(Basic basic)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class AnotherWorker : IWorker<AnotherBasic>
{
    public void Run(AnotherBasic basic)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Final
{
    public void Test()
    {
        List<IWorker<AnotherBasic>> workers = new List<IWorker<AnotherBasic>>
        {
            new SimpleWorker(),
            new Worker(),
            new AnotherWorker()
        };
    }
}
```

TBasic in CONTRAVARIANT, which means the declaration should be the most specific as possible, as shown in the code: AnotherBasic
Then the types that are less derived, are the parents, are accepted, and the code compiles.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize it like this:

```
public void Test()
{
    List<IWorker<IBasic>> workers = new List<IWorker<IBasic>>
    {
        new Worker<IBasic>(),
        new AnotherWorker<IBasic>()
    };
    workers[0].Run(new Basic());
}
```

Comment: no, it does not work, both worker and another worker are not generic

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration of workers says "this is a list of workers, and each one can run any implementation of IBasic", which is not true.

What you could try is moving the responsibility of the kind of command the worker can process to the worker itself (in fact, this is what the [chain of responsibility pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) suggests).

```
public interface IWorker
{
    bool DidRun<TBasic>(TBasic basic);
}

public class WorkerChain
{
    private readonly List<IWorker> workers = new List<IWorker>
    {
        new Worker(),
        new AnotherWorker()
    };

    public bool DidRun<T>(T basic)
    {
        return workers.Any(worker => worker.DidRun(basic));
    }
}

public class Worker : IWorker
{
    public bool DidRun<T>(T basic)
    {
        if (!(basic is Basic))
        {
            return false;
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"running {basic}");
        return true;
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public void CanRunWorkBasic()
    {
        var didRun = new WorkerChain().DidRun(new Basic());
        Debug.Assert(didRun);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert your workers into a list, you will need a non-generic interface `IWorker` and `IWorker<TBasic>` has to implement that interface. Then use `IWorker` instead of `IWorker<TBasic>` in a `List`. Now there are no more problems with adding your workers to a `List`.

This way we have solved one problem, but unfortunately we have also created another one because we have to implement `Run` method twice. Once for a non-generic interface and second time for the generic one.

You can overcome the problem using an abstract `Worker` class which, by default when the non-generic `Run` is called, makes neccessary checks, casts the parameter and pass it to the generic `Run` method. Then your workers can derrive from `Worker` and each one can have its own role.

In the example below I've tried to show how, in my opinion, this code should look like. Non-generic `Run` method is implemented [explicitly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx) and to be safe I also used [generic type constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx). `Run` method just checks for the type and passes it further.

```
public interface IBasic
{

}

public class Basic : IBasic
{

}

public class AnotherBasic : Basic
{

}

public interface IWorker
{
    void Run(IBasic basic);
}

public interface IWorker<in TBasic> : IWorker where TBasic : IBasic
{
    void Run(TBasic basic);
}

public abstract class Worker<TBasic> : IWorker<TBasic> where TBasic : IBasic
{
    void IWorker.Run(IBasic basic)
    {
        if (basic is TBasic)
            Run((TBasic)basic);
    }

    public abstract void Run(TBasic basic);
}

public class FirstWorker : Worker<Basic>
{
    public override void Run(Basic basic)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

public class SecondWorker : Worker<AnotherBasic>
{
    public override void Run(AnotherBasic basic)
    {
        // ...
    }
}


public void Test()
{
    List<IWorker> workers = new List<IWorker>
    {
        new FirstWorker(),
        new SecondWorker()
    };
}
```